# Randomly pick a value from each list in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, random

I have the following code:

```
result = set()
with open("words.txt") as fd:    
    for line in fd:
        matching_words = {word for word in line.lower().split() if len(word)==4 and "'" not in word}
        result.update(matching_words)      
print(result)
print(len(result))

result_dict = {}

for word in result:
    result_dict[word[2:]] = result_dict.get(word[2:], []) + [word]
print(result_dict)
print({key: len(value) for key, value in result_dict.items()})
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWTzK.png)

This takes a .txt file finds all the unique four letter words and excludes any that include an apostrophe. These words are then split using the last 2 characters. Each of the word endings are then added to a dictionary with the number of words containing that ending displayed as the value.

What I now need to do is disregard any list with less than 30 words in it.
Then randomly select one word from each of the remaining lists and print the list of words.

Comment: Seems like a very straightforward programming task using `random.choice()`. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes I am attempting to use random.choise. My issue is in excluding lists with less than 30 words in and then picking a word from each of the remaining lists randomly.

Comment: listunder30 = result_dict.items() < 30

item = random.choice(lists[listunder30s])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following comprehension should work:

```
[random.choice(v) for v in result_dict.values() if len(v) >= 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `random.choice` and use a list comprehension to limit the values given to it:

```
random.choice([k for k, v in result_dict.items() if len(v) >= 30])
```

Comment: Something like this is exactly what I am looking for. I am running into this error though. '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: This also only selects a random word ending in the dictionary not a random word from each of the lists in the dictionary